# Configure Outlook to defer message delivery until a specific time

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, productivity

Is it possible to configure Outlook 2010 to defer the delivery of all messages until a specific time of day?

I know that it's possible to create a rule for outbound messages that will defer delivery by up to 2 hours, but I would prefer to have all of my messages sent at the same time. It's also possible to set the delivery time for each specific message, but that is cumbersome and dependent on me remembering to set it for every message.

Ideally I would like to have an popup menu in the message composition toolbar that allowed me to defer messages to noon or the end of the business day. Even better if this could be enabled by default. Is there a plug-in that provides this functionality?

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just work in offline mode until you're ready to send your messages? Then just go online and click send/receive. (Just click down the bottom in outlook to work offline)

Comment: Thanks, that didn't occur to me. This is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2):

This is the manual way, and quite easy, actually:

**For Microsoft Outlook 2007 & 2010:**

In the open message window, go to the `Options` tab:

[image]

then click `Delay Delivery`:

[image]

This brings up a dialog box with all kinds of options for delaying or scheduling when to send the message, such as "Don't send before 6 AM" (useful for when you write an email in the middle of the night, but want to send it during reasonable hours, etc).

[image]

*Note that if you are using a POP3 or IMAP email account, Outlook has to stay open in order to send the email.*

For more information, you can visit [Delay or schedule sending email](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/delay-or-schedule-sending-email-messages-HP010355051.aspx).

Comment: This is very well written, but in the question I stated that I already know how to set the delivery time for a single message.

Comment: @Nic I apologize, I read most all of the post, but that. I would delete it, but I put enough work in it and it might be useful down the road, so I'm leaving it.  Hope you get a suitable answer. Cheers! :)

Comment: is it possible defer delivery using powershell?

Comment: The delay delivery does not change all the times in the email metadata. The message will still display the 'send' button-click-time rather then the delayed time desired.